# Measuring Topic-coherence score & optimal number of topics in LDA Topic Modeling in Orange data mining

Tags: deep-learning, data-mining, text-mining, orange, topic-model

I'm trying to build an Orange workflow to perform LDA topic modeling for analyzing a text corpus (.CSV dataset).

Unfortunately, the LDA widget in Orange lacks for advanced settings when comparing it with traditional coding in R or Python, which are commonly used for such purposes.

Accordingly, I would inquire about how to use Orange to:

1. Measure (estimate) the optimal (best) number of topics ⁉️.
2. Measuring topic-coherence score in LDA Topic Model in order to evaluate the quality of the extracted topics and their correlation relationships (if any) for extracting useful information ⁉️.

Is there a simple way that can accomplish these tasks in Orange ⁉️.

The following link provides the traditional solution for calculating the topic coherence score using Jupiter-Python as pre-explained ✅

[Article Source link](https://towardsdatascience.com/end-to-end-topic-modeling-in-python-latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda-35ce4ed6b3e0)

I assembled the code-cells into a single file attached below:

[Full Jupiter-Python Code:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1be8rPO3YXRFW3Z5M5C7h4s6rR2zWuT-W/view)

[Sample Dataset Corpus](https://drive.google.com/file/d/197XdefUKShGpEUGNWojzcfZ1UK2qj2Lu/view?usp=sharing)

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Thanks for your cooperation in advance.